# jersey Viewable and c:import tag lib

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

Giver a resource class that has a method witch returns a Viewable (or generaly any jsp page). Is there a way to use the c:import or jsp:include taglib to include a Viewable response from a jaxrs anotatted class? For example given the class

```
@Path("/some/path")
public class SomeJaxrsResource {
  @GET
  public Viewable get() {
    return new Viewable("/the/path/to/the/jsp", this)
  }
}
```

Is there a way to include it's computed html within a jsp with
a

```
<c:import url="/some/path" />
```

or a

```
<jsp:include page="/some/path" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Jersey 1.3  this works, at least with URLs under management of Jersey. This was listed as fixed in the [changelog](http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/tags/jersey-1.13/jersey/changes.txt)

A quick test revealed that it also works with external URLs and URLS in the same servlet context but not under management of Jersey.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I can say that this is not yet possible!